# Returning multiple grandchildren of child of parent from Entity Framework .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework-6, visual-studio-2017

I am using VS2017, to create an ASP.NET Web Application (not using CORE), .NET Framework is 4.6.2 and the Entity Framework .NET is 6.1.3. I have looked on here for my answer but everything that I have tried or that was mentioned is not available to me.

I have the following code to acquire grandchildren of children of a particular parent right now, I know there has to be a more efficient way of acquiring those grandchildren but cannot figure out how:

```
            using (_ge = new generation_entities())
        {
            if (_id != null)
            {
                List<scheduleheader> _tlist = (from a in _ge.scheduleheaders.Include("scheduledetails") where a.programID == _id select a).ToList();
                foreach (scheduleheader _t in _tlist)
                {
                    foreach (scheduledetail _s in _t.scheduledetails)
                    {
                        _s.scheddtlcustoms = (from a in _ge.scheddtlcustoms where a.dtlID == _s.dtlID select a).ToList();
                        _s.scheddtlstandards = (from a in _ge.scheddtlstandards where a.dtlID == _s.dtlID select a).ToList();
                        _s.scheddtltalks = (from a in _ge.scheddtltalks where a.dtlID == _s.dtlID select a).ToList();
                        _s.scheddtlvenues = (from a in _ge.scheddtlvenues where a.dtlID == _s.dtlID select a).ToList();
                        _s.scheduledtlrecurrences = (from a in _ge.scheduledtlrecurrences where a.dtlID == _s.dtlID select a).ToList();
                    }
                }
                return _tlist;
            }
            else
                return (from a in _ge.scheduleheaders where a.scheduledetails.Any(b => b.start > DateTime.Today.AddDays(-30)) && a.programID == null select a).ToList();
        }
```

I have tried using `.ThenInclude` and `Include("xxxx.xxxx.xxxx")` however, `.ThenInclude` is not even available to me and the `Include("xxxx.xxxx.xxxx")` only works for one grandchild. The `Include()` only allows me to enter a string path and yet I have seen comments that the OP was using an older version of EF.

I am stuck on this, can I be enlightened on if I am missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain multiple `Include("xxxx.xxxx.xxxx")` as pointed out in another answer.

However, this will replace the current `parents.Count * children.Count * grandChildrenTypes.Count` number of SQL queries with single, but monster SQL query consolidating all the columns and all the records in a single result set, which may not be efficient as well.

I would suggest you a hybrid approach (similar to the way EF Core processes the `Include`s) which will execute 1 SQL per parents, 1 per children and 1 per each grandchildren **type**, i.e. in this particular case total 7 SQL queries. Only the parent query result is stored into variable, the children and grandchildren queries are just executed, and the whole dirty work is done by EF navigation property fix-up:

```
// Load parents
var parentQuery = _ge.scheduleheaders.Where(a => a.programID == _id);
var parents = parentQuery.ToList();
// Load children
var childQuery = parentQuery.SelectMany(p => p.scheduledetails);
childQuery.Load();
// Load grandchildren
childQuery.SelectMany(c => c.scheddtlcustoms).Load();
childQuery.SelectMany(c => c.scheddtlstandards).Load();
childQuery.SelectMany(c => c.scheddtltalks).Load();
childQuery.SelectMany(c => c.scheddtlvenues).Load();
childQuery.SelectMany(c => c.scheduledtlrecurrences).Load();
// Done
return parents;
```

Comment: I am going to try this and I will let you know how it works out.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like:

```
            var query = context
                    .Parents
                    .Include(p=>p.children)
                    .Include(p=>p.children.Select(x=>x.Grandchild1))
                    .Include(p=>p.children.Select(x=>x.Grandchild2))
                    .ToList();
```

you could access this with `linq`, you might have an id where you could do something like:

```
var grandchild6 = query
                   .children
                  .FirstOrDefault(child=>child.Id =1)
                 ?.GranChildern
                 ?.FirstOrDefault(grandChild=>grandchild.Id = 6);
```

Comment: For some odd reason it only allows me to enter a string within the Include brackets.

Comment: you may have to add `using System.Data.Entity` to the using statments

Comment: thank you for that `using` tip. Your solution works very well, however I do have a small extended question in regards to great grandchildren. say of `x.Grandchild1`. How would I go about getting that, I have already tried to mimic the include but cannot seem to get it to work